# How to download the file through filezilla client?

Tags: linux, putty, filezilla

I would like to download the application log file through filezilla. i have to access the log file through putty(first login with my username and passport) after that get into the directory and "sudo su - csuser", then it will ask password and get into the files directory and can see the file using "less -f filename".

But this process very hard to me to see the log file.So i want to download the file through filezilla.
I'm able to go to the directory using my username and password but restricted to use only csuser.
Is there any way i can login as csuser as like putty ?? or any command to download the file from putty ?

Thanks

Comment: what does this mean: "but restricted to use only csuser"? Do you mean you can only read the file if you are `csuser`?

Comment: i mean csuser can read/write.

Comment: but if you are not csuser, then you cannot read it, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to you some alternative options (you should check that you are permitted to do the ones after the first one, before doing them):

1. Learn to use `less` properly. It's really quite a nice program, you can search with `/` for example.
2. Change the permission on the file so that you can read it, with the `chmod` command.
3. If you are not allowed to do that, write a cron job that runs as `csuser` to copy the file over to your user.

By the way, `less -f` is probably not what you want, unless it is a "special file". You are probably confusing it with `tail -f`, or `less +F --follow-name`.